# What is theForm.onsubmit()?

Tags: javascript, dom-events

Can someone explain this function for me? What do `!theForm.onsubmit()` and `theForm.onsubmit() != false` mean?

```
//<![CDATA[
var theForm = document.forms['Form'];
if (!theForm) {
    theForm = document.Form;
}
function __doPostBack(eventTarget, eventArgument) {
    if (!theForm.onsubmit || (theForm.onsubmit() != false)) {
        theForm.__EVENTTARGET.value = eventTarget;
        theForm.__EVENTARGUMENT.value = eventArgument;
        theForm.submit();
    }
}
//]]>
```

And when I checked with the console I got this:

```
!theForm.onsubmit
true
theForm.onsubmit
null
!null
true
```

What is the meaning of `theForm.onsubmit`, how can it be `null` and `!null` be true?

And when I checked `theForm.onsubmit() != false` I got:

```
theForm.onsubmit()
TypeError: object is not a function
theForm.onsubmit() != false
TypeError: object is not a function
```

What is the difference by the way between `theForm.onsubmit` and `theForm.onsubmit()`?

Answer (score 2):

`theForm.onsubmit` is an event handler for the `submit` event. If it is `null`, no handler has been set. When it is set, it should be a function. `theForm.onsubmit()` calls the function, just like any other.

You are getting that error with `theForm.onsubmit()` because apparently, no handler has been set. You need to execute the entire expression together.

---

```
if (!theForm.onsubmit || (theForm.onsubmit() != false))
```

If there is no handler, or calling the handler returns false, execute the code block.